# Directing OneDrive on a device via JavaScript/web app

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, onedrive

Is it possibly, from a website, to direct OneDrive on a user's device (iPad) to capture a photo and store it in a specific folder? Is it possible to direct OneDrive on a user's device to create a folder in the same manner?

The use case is basically we want the web application to control workflow, but outsource the photo capturing and asynchronous uploading of photos to OneDrive. But we know where the photos are and what they're named, so we can download them onto our server later when they have finished uploading and are available in the cloud.

Comment: so you want to to capture a picture using iPad camera and want to upload it to one drive. Is that you want?

Comment: It's probably not feasible as it's a cross-browser/device idea but with offline HTML5 apps and increasing browser support for device services (camera, geolocation) I'd thought I'd ask. What I want to do is use a web browser to request that a photo is taken and stored on the device and that OneDrive on the device take care of syncing the file on the device to the cloud into a OneDrive folder that the website is aware of.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing mobile's camera from mobile, you can use input tag as following:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Now to upload the file you can use OneDrive JS SDK like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function launchSaveToOneDrive() {
    var odOptions = { /* ... specify the desired options ... */ };
    OneDrive.save(odOptions);
  }
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileUploadControl" name="fileUploadControl" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

<button onclick="launchSaveToOneDrive">Save to OneDrive</button>
```

where odOptions will look like this:

```
var odOptions = {
  clientId: "INSERT-APP-ID-HERE",
  action: "save",
  sourceInputElementId: "fileUploadControl",
  sourceUri: "",
  fileName: "file.txt",
  openInNewWindow: true,
  advanced: {},
  success: function(files) { /* success handler */ },
  progress: function(p) { /* progress handler */ },
  cancel: function() { /* cancel handler */ },
  error: function(e) { /* error handler */ }
}
```

Your success will response will have the URL of OneDrive uploaded file which will be passed to success callback as param.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "123456",
      "name": "document1.docx",
      "size": 12340,
      "@content.downloadUrl": "https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/download.aspx?guid=1231231231a",
      "webUrl": "https://cotoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_contoso_com/documents/document1.docx",
      "thumbnails": [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "small": { "url": "https://sn3302files.onedrive.live.com/..." },
          "medium": { "url": "https://sn3302files.onedrive.live.com/..." },
          "large": { "url": "https://sn3302files.onedrive.live.com/..." }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For more see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/save-file)

Comment: Hi, this solution uploads the file using the website. I am looking to offload that responsibility to OneDrive on the users phone (e.g. like Dropbox's Camera Uploads). This is so the user can take a photo and the website knows where to find it on OneDrive (once it's uploaded), but the user can close the website and the upload will be done by OneDrive on the device in the background.